# How to add a static parameter to a SQL query using SqlCommand C#

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

Is it possible to add a static parameter to a SQL query using a `SqlCommand` in C#?

I am trying to either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a database table depending on if a client already exists.

I am trying to make the `UpdateType` = 1 if `INSERT` is executed OR 2 if `UPDATE` is executed.

Is there a way to remove the dynamic parameter `@UpdateType` and just a static value 1 or 2 for either INSERT or UPDATE queries?

Here is an example of the query:

```
string sqlQuery = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Client WHERE [ClientID] =" +  
    "@ClientID) " +  
    "INSERT INTO Client (ClientId, LastName, FirstName, UpdateType)" + 
    "VALUES (@ClientID, @LastName, @FirstName, @UpdateType)" +
    "ELSE " +  
    "UPDATE Client " + 
    "SET [ClientID] = @ClientID, [LastName] = @LastName, [FirstName] = "+ 
    "@FirstName, [UpdateType] = @UpdateType"+
    "WHERE ClientID = ClientID;";

using (SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, SQLConn))
{
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.Int);

    try
    {
        SQLConn.Open();

        foreach (DataRow row in SourceData.Rows)
        {
            MyCommand.Parameters["@ClientID"].Value = row["ClientId"].ToString();
            MyCommand.Parameters["LastName"].Value = row["LastName"].ToString();
            MyCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = row["FirstName"].ToString();
            MyCommand.Parameters["@UpdateType"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["UpdateType"]);

            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
     catch
     {
         ....
     }    
}
```

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The really big problem here is your update statement is missing the @ for the parameter. Your query will update every single row.  See answer below

Comment: as @Vincent says try    "WHERE ClientID = @ClientID";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your code cleaner by allowing a multi line string with the @ symbol.

If the record does not exist insert it, otherwise update it setting the values for the record where the ClientId = @ClientId.

And you certainly would not want to do what your query is doing. Updating  the table using the where clause `WHERE ClientId = ClientId`, will in effect, update every row in the table.

```
        string sqlQuery = @"
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Client WHERE [ClientID] = @ClientID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Client (ClientId, LastName, FirstName, UpdateType)
    VALUES (@ClientID, @LastName, @FirstName, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE Client SET 
        [LastName] = @LastName,
        [FirstName] = @FirstName,
        [UpdateType] = 2
    WHERE
        ClientID = @ClientID;//<<<fix your query!!!!!
END;"

using (SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, SQLConn))
{
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    try{
        SQLConn.Open();
        foreach (DataRow row in SourceData.Rows)
        {
            MyCommand.Parameters["@ClientID"].Value = row["ClientId"].ToString();
            MyCommand.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = row["LastName"].ToString();
            MyCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = row["FirstName"].ToString();
        }
     }catch{
         ....
     }    
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, it's easier for everybody to read an explanation instead of trying to figure out by ourselves. : ).

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. What doesn't make sense here. If a record does not exist insert it, otherwise update it. No need to pass in the parameter for update type since it is handled by the SQL IF/ELSE. Reading other peoples code is a challenging process but it is how we learn. You look at it, look at it again, and than a little light goes on and you learned something knew.

Comment: That's correct, I am not talking about me, consider that SO is a huge site where a lot of developers with different set of skills come to learn something new.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Thanks for your help. I will be using the update type for POST = 1 and PUT = 2  in a restful call. After the calls I reset input type to 0. So basically, this is just a staging table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just remove the @UpdateType from the sql and replace it with 1 or 2

```
...
"(@ClientID, @LastName, @FirstName, 1)" +
"ELSE " +  
"UPDATE Client " + 
"SET [ClientID] = @ClientID, [LastName] = @LastName, [FirstName] = "+ 
"@FirstName, [UpdateType] = 2"+
...
```

Remove the rest of the code that mentions it too:

```
MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdateType", SqlDbType.Int);
```

And

```
MyCommand.Parameters["@UpdateType"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row["UpdateType"]);
```

PS- using @ strings in c# allows you to insert new lines in the string constant which makes it a lot more readable:

```
var sql = @"select *
  from
    Table
  where
    Blah = 1";
```

Than having that "+" all over the place. You should perhaps put your sql strings in a resource file or similar though. Or a stored procedure